# How to make scopes with different settings in settings.json file | VSCode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings

I want to change colors of my color theme in VSCode and I got stuck with `scope` and `settings` properties in settings.json file.

```
        "[Palenight Theme]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": ["string.quoted.double.html",
                            "meta.attribute.content.html",
                            "meta.tag.metadata.meta.void.html",
                            "text.html.derivative",
                            ], 
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#bcb9ff",
                    },
                }
            ],
        }
```

I tried to add another `scope` and `settings` properties but it doesn't work, it completely overrides the first one even though it contains completely different properties.

```
        "[Palenight Theme]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": ["string.quoted.double.html",
                            "meta.attribute.content.html",
                            "meta.tag.metadata.meta.void.html",
                            "text.html.derivative",
                            ], 
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#bcb9ff",
                    },
                    //Completely overrides the first one.
                    "scope": ["entity.name.tag.html",], 
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#fff",
                    },
                }
            ],
        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: create a new object in the array of `textMateRules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rivo8 said, instead of adding properties to the body of the first object, you should add a new object the the `"textMateRules"` array, basically doing it like this:

```
    "[Palenight Theme]": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": ["string.quoted.double.html",
                    "meta.attribute.content.html",
                    "meta.tag.metadata.meta.void.html",
                    "text.html.derivative",
                    ], 
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#bcb9ff",
            },
        },
        {
          //Completely overrides the first one.
          "scope": ["entity.name.tag.html",], 
          "settings": {
                "foreground": "#fff",
          },
        },
    ],
}
```